# In Matlab is there any way to disable rotation estimation when calculating transform between two scenes?

Tags: matlab, transform, estimation

I am currently using Matlab estimateGeometricTransform function to estimate transform between two scenes taken by different sensors. If I know there are only translation and scale changes between these two scenes, is there any way I can disable rotation estimation?

I tried Similarity, Affine and Protective but all of them contain rotation estimation which will mess up the results because of the dis-ambiguity between rotation and translation.

Comment: I believe so. In the `affine2d` rotation transform example in https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2017b/images/ref/affine2d.html , I'll just end up setting the `transform` matrix to have the `rotation` values to be all zeros and have only the `translation` components populated. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: @Jerry Thanks for your reply. Is affine2d able to handle scale also? Since my situation needs to handle both x y change and z scale changes.

Comment: @Jerry Also, I think what I am looking for is a method to completely disable rotation estimation or rotation search during transform estimation. Simply set rotation value to zero in the end may not work since those rotations is actually compensate motion caused by translation or scaling.

Comment: Try using `fitgeotrans` https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fitgeotrans.html#bvonaug . Obtain the returned `tform` and see if the pipeline procedures in https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/2-d-and-3-d-geometric-transformation-process-overview.html#f12-33299 helps to remove the rotation estimate.